# CentOS7でSSH接続ができない　Teratermで認証失敗になる

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

### Teratermで認証に失敗してしまう

さくらのVPSでCentOS7をインストールしましたが、Teratermで認証に失敗してしまいます。

公開鍵`id_rsa.pub`は~/.ssh/authorized_keysに、秘密鍵`id_rsa`はクライアント側にあります。

OpenSSHは以下のように設定しました。

```
Port 1583
PermitRootLogin no 
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AllowUsers （一般ユーザー名）
```

Teratermからポート番号1583で接続はできるようになりましたが、今度は認証に失敗してしまいます...

VNCコンソールから、`# ssh -p [ポート番号] [一般ユーザー名]@[IPアドレス]`で接続しようとするとパーミッションエラーになります

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

SELinuxも無効にしました。（`# getenforce`と入れると`disabled`と返ってきます。）

`/var/log/secure`を見てみると、画像のようになっていました。

https://kie.nu/2Kww

いろいろ調べましたが、これ以上は追究できませんでした。
何度もsshdを再起動しましたが、ダメでした。

知恵を貸していただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

質問内容を編集しました。

とりあえず接続はできるようになりましたが、# ssh コマンドでログインができず、Teratermで認証に失敗してしまいます。

改めてお願いします。

---

*接続できるまでの流れ*

`/etc/firewalld/services/ssh.xml`をもともと以下のように複数指定していました

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
<short>SSH</short>
<description>（略）</description>

<port protocol="tcp" port="1583"/>
<port protocol="tcp" port="80"/>
<port protocol="tcp" port="8080"/>
</service>
```

それを1つだけ指定にしたところ、Teratermから接続ができるようになりました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
<short>SSH</short>
<description>（略）</description>

<port protocol="tcp" port="1583"/>
</service>
```

直近の`/var/log/secure`（9月30日の夜中～10月1日の夜）は以下です。

https://kie.nu/2KEt

どうやら

```
error: bind to port [ポート番号] on 0.0.0.0 failed: permission denied.
fatal: cannot bind any address.
```

というエラーがなくなったようです。

---

Comment: 念の為に確認しますけれども、公開鍵はサーバ側の `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` に追加してありますよね？

Comment: ＞argusさん
コメントありがとうございます。
たぶん~/.ssh/authorized_keysに上げたと思います。
こちらを参考にしました。
https://help.sakura.ad.jp/app/answers/detail/a_id/2425

Comment: もしかして、`~/.ssh` ディレクトリや `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ファイルのオーナーが root になっていたりしませんか？

Comment: どちらもrootになっていました。一般ユーザーに変える必要があるんでしょうか。一応、chownコマンドで所有権を一般ユーザーにしてみましたが、ログインできませんでした。

Comment: ええと、もしかして root で SSH ログインしようとしていますか？

Comment: いえ、一般ユーザー名とパスフレーズと秘密鍵でのログインを試みています。

Comment: 現状、ログインができていないので関係のない話になりますが、その一般ユーザのホームディレクトリに .ssh ディレクトリを作成して authorized_keys ファイルを置いたのですよね。ディレクトリやファイルのパーミッションは 0700 や 0600 に設定したでしょうから、オーナーが root になっていると、その一般ユーザ権限では読めません。ですので、オーナーは一般ユーザにしておく必要があるわけです。

Comment: なるほど、ユーザーをそろえておく必要があるんですね。ありがとうございます。初心者ですみません。

Comment: 接続できないという問題はどのように解決したのでしょうか。/var/log/secure はどのように変化したのでしょうか。問題が解決する度、次の問題の質問に書き変えてしまうと知見が集積せず、もったいないと思います。

Comment: >mjyさん　コメントありがとうございます。/var/log/secureの変化と、接続できない問題の解決を質問に書き加えました。何も考えず試したことなので、知見だなんてとんでもないです。「やってみたらたまたまできた」という感じなので．．．mjyさんの知見を頂けたら嬉しいです。

Comment: サーバ側で `ls -la ~starter/.ssh` を実行した結果を教えていただけますか？

Comment: >argusさん　`ls: cannot access /home/starter/.ssh: No such file or directory`と出ました。今は`home/.ssh/authorized_keys`にあるので場所が違っていたのでしょうか。とりあえず mv コマンドで移動させてみます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事にログインできました！

Comment: コメント欄でディスカッションするのはやめましょう。また、質問者の方はコメントのやりとりで解決したのであれば、ご自分でその内容を回答に転記して承認しておいてください。承認しないといつまでも未回答として残ってしまいます

Comment: >suzukisさん　ご指摘感謝します。以後気を付けます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

home/.ssh/authorized_keysだったのをhome/[一般ユーザー名]/.ssh/authorized_keysに変更したらログインできるようになりました。